# How to handle an interface that may require different parameters for implementation?

Tags: php, oop, interface

I have the following interface:

```
interface LinkGeneratorInterface
{
    public function generateLink();
}
```

My application requires a function to generate a link to redirect a user to. In the future, I may need to change how link generation occurs. Right now, here is my simple FakeLinkGenerator:

```
class FakeLinkGenerator implements LinkGeneratorInterface
{
    public function generateLink()
    {
        return "https://stackoverflow.com";
    }
}
```

But what if, in the future, my link generation will require additional parameters. Take the following example

```
class RealLinkGenerator implements LinkGeneratorInterface
{
    public function generateLink($parameter)
    {
        // business logic with $parameter

        return "https://stackoverflow.com"; // may append stuff depending on my business logic
    }
}
```

This would require me to change the interface, which defeats the purpose of coding to an interface. If I have this function which relies on this abstraction `LinkGeneratorInterface`:

```
public function getLink(LinkGeneratorInterface $generator)
{
    return $generator->generateLink();
}
```

I will also have to change this implementation as well. I want to be able to specify different `LinkGeneratorInterface` to this function.

**Note:** My link generation may rely on user input, so injecting parameters via the constructor is not an option.

Comment: I'd go for assoc array for parameters (empty default), throws exception on missing required key-value pair and appends query string for undefined keys. I don't like `generateLink()` method name (without parameters) anyway - no one should care if fully encapsulated link is generated or not.

Answer (score 1):

> But what if, in the future, my link generation will require additional parameters. Take the following example

Then you create new method, or change your interface even at cost of breaking backward compatibility. It's up to you to decide which way would work for you better.

> defeats the purpose of coding to an interface

You misunderstand the concept of interface - it's NOT a non-alterable concrete block. You change it when needed as needed. If you think you change it too often then perhaps what's flaky is your software design
as you simply did not foresee far too many things your interface should help define.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few options here:

- Optional Parameters

A dirty (in my opinion) way of doing this is to use optional parameters:

```
class FakeLinkGenerator implements LinkGeneratorInterface
{
    public function generateLink($param = 'defaultValue')
    {
        return "https://stackoverflow.com/$param";
    }
}
```

This will pass the validation of the interface and allow you great flexibility in creating implementations. This works great when there is effectively a sane default value to be used. What makes it less than optional is when the argument is not optional, and we use this trick only to pass validation. This leads to additional overhead (this optional parameter is not optional) and is more likely to cause problems.

- Constructor Injection

A somewhat cleaner way of doing this, cleaner because we leave the method signature intact, is to inject the parameter from the concrete class constructor and use it in the implementing method:

```
class FakeLinkGenerator implements LinkGeneratorInterface
{
    private $param;

    public function __construct($param) { $this->param = $param; }

    public function generateLink()
    {
        return "https://stackoverflow.com/{$this->param}";
    }
}
```

This is my preferred method. In theory, this is also a valid way; an interface is supposed to define member through which we communicate with an object, leaving the implementation details to said object. Ideally, we should not do work in the constructor. For these reasons, we can distillate a soft rule not to define a constructor's arguments in an interface, leaving us the freedom to use this method.